# Is the set $\{<M> | L(M) \text{is a finite set}\}$ RE, co-RE or neither?

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem

$<M>$ is the encoding of a TM and L(M) is the language accepted.

Comment: When you wrote $L(M)\; is\; finite\; set$ - do you mean it it's have finite amount of words? I.e. the is a number $n$ of acceptable words?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean